# Microservices - remove unnecessary boilerplate?

Tags: architecture, java-ee, microservices

My thoughts:

- microservices are becoming popular for distributed architecture
- java is (for now) a main course in enterprise applications
- JEE stack too

How to reduce a boilerplate (including Maven scripts, etc.) for microservices? It is really painfull having repeated code twice or more times. Is there any good solution/behavior/attitude for staying in JEE stack and just don't messing with these repeated boileplate issues?

Comment: Well honestly I see very limited dependency on the JEE stack in general besides the use of the servlet container. I see Spring making quite a lot of progress in Microservices and you don't need a container to work with spring.

Comment: What exactly boilerplate do you mean? Something JEE specific? Or some generic approach to architecture micro-services?